# How would you speed up a for loop like this in R?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply

My code has a for loop that is taking ages for running. I was wondering how can speed up it by using one of the apply family functions available in R.

The for loop that I want to change would look like this:

```
for (i in range(1:200000)){
    a[i] = gsub(pattern[i],new_pattern[i])
}
```

Where pattern and new_pattern are both lists. What I want to achieve is to change a character pattern in each line for a new one. I have tried the following:

```
sapply(c(1:200000),function(x) gsub(pattern[x],new_pattern[x], a[x]))
```

But it is taking very long too. Any suggestions of how can I improve my code to be faster?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The looping is completely unnecessary, gsub like almost all functions in base package is already vectorized. Just do gsub(patter, new_pattern, a) instead.

Comment: As @kliron said, many functions in R are vectorized. For-loops have their uses, but they're rarely needed.

Comment: @kliron not quite, `gsub` can't accept a vector of patterns and replacements. It is only vectorized over `x`. This is why OP needs to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If all you care about is speeding up a loop trying going parallel with 'foreach'

Comment: @Carl feel free to add your solution. An improvement can be made with stringr package.

Comment: @Carl or using the builtin parallel package. Do mind that you have to take care how you do the parallelization, or else it might up taking even longer...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra good point

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed with `str_replace_all` from `stringr` package using a named vector:

```
library(stringr)

x = 'dog likes cat very much'
str_replace_all(x, setNames(c('babyboy','babygirl'), c('dog','cat')))

#[1] "babyboy likes babygirl very much"
```

**Performance:** 7-8 times faster

```
set.seed(1)
x = paste0(sample(c(letters,' '), 100000, replace=T, prob=c(rep(1/39, 26), 1/3)), collapse='')

patt = apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse='')
repl = as.character(1:456976)

system.time({
    for (i in 1:456976){
        x = gsub(patt[i],repl[i], x)
    }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#1574.41    2.41 1582.71

system.time(str_replace_all(x, setNames(repl, patt)))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 194.04    0.14  194.36
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how the performance of `str_replace_all` compares to looping over `gsub`? I think `str_replace_all` should be faster...